# Is it possible to add IIS caching for dynamic content for my MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, iis-7.5

I have host my MVC application in IIS. I am aware about adding output caching using IIS for static content. But is it possible to add output caching for dynamic content? How? I am using IIS version 7.5

Thank you.

Comment: You need to enable caching of dynamic content in IIS features and enable it for the site in IIS or through web.config

Comment: How can I enable it in IIS for dynamic content? Or how can I add it in web.config for dynamic pages?

Comment: You can try to google that. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754957(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I don't believe this is what she's after? I'm at least looking for setting Cache-Control header for only dynamic content as setting it as a custom header seems to make it impossible to have something different on Static content (it gets double max-age values then)..

Answer (score 0):

Do you need your cache exactly IIS level?

MVC have it's own cache mechanism. You can use [`OutputCache`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCIQFjABahUKEwjn4casorrHAhUC4XIKHdORDYc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v%3Dvs.118).aspx&ei=3iXXVef6C4LCywPTo7a4CA&usg=AFQjCNHW86u5YJlOXgepRsKnSAEkeGlrtw&sig2=vTZNMcQGALVFl0_A8QBM9A&cad=rja) attribute.

This attribute have parameter `VaryByParam` so you can cache dynamic content like this:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 30, VaryByParam = "Id;PersonId;AnotherId")]
```

This attribute allow you to cache for 30 seconds controller (Or Action) output in respect to different values of `Id`, `PersonId`, `AnotherId` params that come to it.

Comment: Thank you for your response and yes I am aware with this too. But caching for dynamic content at IIS level and caching we add at action method both are the same thing?

Comment: @Ankita no, it's definatly not the same. The can acting same if you config them right but they are using different backgroud mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow teo van kot's answer. You can set VaryByParam in Globals.asax.cs file. IIS 7.5 doesn't matter here.

You can cache the different content for different people that way.

A more specific solution is

```
 HttpContext.Cache.Add("latest",data);
```

use this HttpContext.Cache to store the data and get it in other http request. You can make your own multiple condition and mechanism to store the data in HttpContext.cache and use it in your own way.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will apply your solution.